# dplyr v0.3 left_join error

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm not being able to `left_join` with dplyr 0.3 when trying to use `by` argument.

First, I installed v0.3 following Hadley's suggestion on [github](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr#dplyr)

```
if (packageVersion("devtools") < 1.6) {
  install.packages("devtools")
}
devtools::install_github("hadley/lazyeval")
devtools::install_github("hadley/dplyr")

sessioninfo()
#    R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
#Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
#
#locale:
#[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Portugal.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Portugal.1252   
#[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Portugal.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                        
#[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Portugal.1252    
#
#attached base packages:
#[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#
#other attached packages:
#[1] dplyr_0.3
#
#loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#[1] assertthat_0.1 DBI_0.3.1      magrittr_1.0.1 parallel_3.1.1 Rcpp_0.11.2    tools_3.1.1
```

Then taking some data

```
df1<-as.tbl(data.frame('var1'=LETTERS[1:10],'value1'=sample(1:100,10), stringsAsFactors = F))
df2<-as.tbl(data.frame('var2'=LETTERS[1:10],'value2'=sample(1:100,10), stringsAsFactors = F))
library(dplyr)
```

And finally trying to `left_join`

```
left_join(df1, df2, by = c('var1' = 'var2'))
# Error: cannot join on column 'var1'
```

But it works with

```
df2$var1 <- df2$var2

left_join(df1, df2, by = c('var1' = 'var2'))
    Source: local data frame [10 x 4]

   var1 value1 var2 value2
1     A     37    A     48
2     B     90    B     18
3     C     13    C     36
4     D     94    D     75
5     E     14    E     12
6     F     95    F     52
7     G     60    G     55
8     H     69    H     72
9     I     25    I     49
10    J     47    J     10
```

My questions

Is `dplyr` ignoring the `by` argument in the second example?
Can this be a bug?

Comment: Why don't you directly ask the creator, before publicly claiming it might be a bug?

Comment: well, just to know if I'm doing something wrong here, before asking unnecessarily. Could be my system? just to know if anyone reproduce the error.

Comment: I tried your code with dplyr 0.2, and I had an error message. I think you need common names in `by`. From the CRAN manual: `by: a character vector of variables to join by. If NULL, the default, join will do a natural join, using all variables with common names across the two tables.` By the way, `merge(df1,df2, by.x = "var1", by.y = "var2")` is OK.

Comment: I installed dplyr 0.3 yesterday, and all your examples work fine for me (on the same platform and R version).

Comment: I'll try re-installing dplyr.

Comment: It is working now. A update to dplyr on github was done a few hours ago.